# chattr +i does not work as a thunar custom action

Tags: thunar, ubuntu-mate

This Thunar custom action is not working when used in 20.04. It works in 18.04?

```
sudo chattr -f  +i %f
```

This does not work either.

```
pkexec chattr -f +i %f
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the password in single quotes is important.

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S chattr +i %f
```

Comment: You should note that it was not taking your password, or that you want to echo it and not type it in.